# Apigee BaaS emails me weird error messages

Tags: apigee

I am using Apigee BaaS and everytime I run the cordova app that consumes these apis I get this error message in an email

[org-name-app-name timeStamp Sat Dec 27 19:52:03 UTC 2014][ Tag : CRASH][ Device Platform : android][ Platform Version : android UNKNOWN][ Device Model : UNKNOWN][ Devicd ID :794DCBC2-4D1D-9EEC-A86560412878]Error:[object Event] for url:undefined on line:undefined

What exactly is this? Why do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apigeee BaaS SDKs also include App Performance Monitoring (APM) functionalities. APM catches crashes in iOS and Android Apps. When it comes to JS, it captures all errors and will send email notification in group depending on how frequently errors/crashes are happening and some configuration parameters. If you don't want to get notification, then you can turn off entire APM or just crash notification. To disable monitoring completely, see http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/monitoring-app-usage-data . Just to suppress crash notification, see http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/monitoring-app-errors-and-crashes section "Disabling alert.."